# Why is Post code being triggered on jQuery load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, post, get

I have the following functions in my ProceduresControlller:

```
Function Add(ByVal bpid As Integer) As ActionResult
    Return View(GetAvailableProcedures(bpid))
End Function

<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function Add(ByVal bpid As Integer, ByVal code As String, ByVal covered As Boolean) As ActionResult
    AddProcedure(bpid, codes, covered)
    Return View("Close")
End Function
```

I'm loading the Add dialog via jQuery like so:

```
$("#dialog").load(
    "/Procedures/Add",
    { bpid: 123 },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

This is failing because it's calling the Post method (where "covered" can't be empty) instead of the Get. I tried decorating the Get with `<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)>`, but it doesn't change the outcome.

Why is this triggering the Post, and how do I get it to use the Get? I realize I could change the names to not be ambiguous, but I want to know why it won't pick the Get if I'm only passing "bpid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery API reference for Ajax.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load):

> A GET request will be performed by default - but if you pass in any extra parameters in the form of an Object/Map (key/value pairs) then a POST will occur. Extra parameters passed as a string will still use a GET request.

So I guess you could change it to something like:

```
$("#dialog").load(
    "/Procedures/Add",
    { "bpid" : "123" },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: Yep, completely forgot about that little fact. Thanks.